# How is context switching disabled in a process?

Tags: operating-systems

By what provision is context switching disabled in a process ? Or is it the case that if a process is in in kernel mode , context switching is disabled by default ?

Comment: What does that mean?  You can't "disable context switching in a process", or at least I'm not sure what that would mean.  Where did you get this idea?  Why do you think this is something that is done?  What's the context for where you encountered this and the motivation for why you are asking?  Why do you think that this might be possible?  What would you be trying to achieve?  Do you understand what context switching is and how it works in modern operating systems?  If not, that might be a good place to start your studies.

Comment: If I run some code with infinite loop in kernel mode and disable interrupt in kernel then context switching will get disabled because the code inside kernel mode will never be ending and since interrupt is disabled , no context switching can occur